# React not setState value on form

Tags: reactjs

I'm just starting with React so I've created a basic form with email and password field.

My question is : Why setState is not updating the state?

I've read the docs from React and its says that we can setState using [key] : value when [key] is not hard coded.

Below my code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        mail : "",
        password : ""
    };

  }

  handleInputChange = (event) =>{
   this.setState = ({
       [event.target.name]: event.target.value
   })

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <label>
          Email 
          <input
            name="mail"
            type="mail"
            value={this.state.mail}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
          Mot de passe 
          <input
            name="password"
            type="password"
            value={this.state.password}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `setState` is a function

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the function this way:

```
chandleInputChange = (event) => {
 this.setState({
  [event.target.name]: event.target.value
})
```

Comment: ok just the equal sign was the problem :( thanks for it; i can close the post then

Comment: You've not used seState as a function.